# Adding the sumCol method for 2D array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I am trying to add a `sumCol()` method to my class TwDArray and then invoke it in my TwDArrayApp main method. Here's what I have:

```
public class TwDArray {
    public void sumCols(TwoDArray s1) {
        int[] answer;
        for(int i = 0; i < nRows; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < a[0].length; j++)
                answer = a[j][i] + a[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how to call it in my main method, I started with:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int maxRows = 20;
    int maxCols = 20;
    TwoDArray arr = new TwoDArray(maxRows, maxCols);
    TwoDArray arrb = new TwoDArray(maxRows, maxCols);
    TwoDArray arrc = new TwoDArray(maxRows, maxCols);
    int b[][] = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {11, 22, 33, 44}, {2, 4, 6, 8},                   
            {100, 200, 300, 400}};

    arr.insert(b[0]); arr.insert(b[1]); arr.insert(b[2]);       
    arr.insert(b[3]);

    System.out.println("The original matrix: ");
    arr.display();

    /*arr.sumCols(maxRows, maxCols);*/
    System.out.printf("%4d", sumCols(arr));
}
```

I'm still really new at programming and probably making this harder then what is it. Any directions or suggestions would be appreciated! Please explain your answer with detail so I can understand it. 
--There is extra code in here because I've been trying different lines to see if I can get it to work

Comment: So you want a method that collapses your 2D array into a 1D array by adding all the values together for each column?

Comment: I want to add the rows within each column and then display the sum of each column from the array

Answer (score 0):

Java's `main()` method can only invoke methods that are `static` ie. within the global scope of the program. So you have two options of how to deal with this.

1. You can make your method `static` like so:

   ```
   public static void sumCols(TwoDArray s1){
       // your code
   }
   ```

   And invoke it in your main() method like so(Assuming you've imported
   the class):

   ```
      public static void main(String[] args){
       TwDArray.sumCols(arr)
      }
   ```
2. Or you can leave your method non-static and invoke it via the creation of your class as an object like so:

   ```
    public static void main(String[] args){
      TwDArray yourObject = new TwDArray();
     }
   ```

   And then call it like so

   ```
     yourObject.sumCols(arr);
   ```

Comment: I was trying to keep the method non static and invoke it in my main. I know you have to pass the correct parameters and maybe that's what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: @Jane In that case, the second option is the best course of action. To make sure you are passing the right parameters, try experimenting by printing the contents to the console right before you pass them through the method. This will tell you exactly what you are giving to the method. If it comes out right, try working your way through your method to see if the problem lies there. Just don't give up!

Answer (score 0):

Is your 'TwoDArray' class a different one from 'TwDArray' class? or it's your typo?

If it is different, you can call like:

```
new TwDArray().sumCols(arr);
```

Note: a non-static method belongs to an object, so create an object before you call member method in a class.

Comment: It was a typo, so the two class are TwoDArray and TwoDArrayApp. The app contains my main method to invoke and the TwoDArray is the class where my methods like insert, display, and sumCol is housed